# Photoshop 7 license and commercial use

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have read a Photoshop 7.0 (2002 release) user license but in no place did i find it referred in the licence I could use the software for commercial/business needs. Does it mean I cannot use it commercially if it does not specify/mention I can? It is not a trial/education/student/demonstration but a full retail version. Thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use photoshop for commercial use. You can use any photoshop, even the trial one, for commercial use.

Source: [Adobe-Forum & EULA](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4915990).